# Stuck editing HTML text source as CSS

Tags: html, css

I am stuck in the simple task of editing text in a HTML source as CSS.  I hope someone can help with what I am sure has a very simple answer.  The reason I am having difficulty is because when I try to view the .css files of the webpage I am trying to edit, all the text elements (like text headings etc.) seem to be omitted from the code.  I know nothing about CSS so I am struggling.

Here is the HTML source:

```html
<div>
  <label class='text-contrast'>Check-in</label>
  <input autocomplete='off' required type='text' id='cf-query-start_date' class=' date form-control' value='' data-alt='#alt_cf-query-start_date' data-datepicker='' />
  <input type='hidden' name='start_date' id='alt_cf-query-start_date' class='alt_date' value='2016-11-04'>
</div>
<div class='input-placeholder-group form-group mobile-browser mobidates end_date '>
  <label class='text-contrast'>Check-out</label>
</div>
```

Very simply, I want to change 'Check-in' to 'Date range' and delete 'Check-out' text elements.  Needs to be done using CSS editor.

EDIT: Missing div part:

```
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="text-jumbo text-contrast">REDACTED</h2>
                    <div class="sticker">
            <form method='get' action='/reserve' id='cf-query' class='search-area full form-inline' role='form'>    
        <input type='hidden' name='filter_item_id' id='filter_item_id' value='' />
        <input type='hidden' name='customer_id' value=''/>
        <input type='hidden' name='date' id='date' value='' />
        <input type='hidden' id='widget-arg-item_id' class='cf-widget-arg' name='item_id' value='' /><input type='hidden' name='category_id' id='category_id' value='0'/><input type='hidden' name='view' id='cf-query-view' value='H'/>
        <div class='search-form-input-wrapper'>
        <div class='input-placeholder-group form-group mobile-browser mobidates start_date '>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to do - editing "HTML source as CSS" does not sound like a simple task or seem to make much sense. Can you elaborate a bit more? What's preventing you from editing the HTML source that you pasted?

Comment: Post the missing start `div` so we'll see what can be done.

Comment: Sounds like you want to change the HTML source with CSS, which you basically can't do. There's a few things like the [content property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) but nothing that will do what you're asking (as far as I know).

Comment: What do you mean by CSS editor? Is it a particular software you are referring to? If so which?

Comment: Have edited my original post to include earlier div section.  It is correct that JS is not an option - my only option is a CSS override.  So far I have only been able to hide 'Check-in' or 'Check-out' with the answers provided; I haven't been able to successfully replace.  Or I can have new text appear after 'Check-in' (again, not replacing).

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Assuming the missing start `div` looks like this `<div class='input-placeholder-group form-group mobile-browser mobidates start_date '>`,</strike> you could do

```css
div.start_date label,       /*  this rule take out the Check-in/out labels  */
div.end_date label {
  display: none;
}
div.start_date::before {    /*  this rule add the Date Range  */
  content: 'Date Range'
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="text-jumbo text-contrast">REDACTED</h2>
  <div class="sticker">
    <form method='get' action='/reserve' id='cf-query' class='search-area full form-inline' role='form'>
      <input type='hidden' name='filter_item_id' id='filter_item_id' value='' />
      <input type='hidden' name='customer_id' value='' />
      <input type='hidden' name='date' id='date' value='' />
      <input type='hidden' id='widget-arg-item_id' class='cf-widget-arg' name='item_id' value='' />
      <input type='hidden' name='category_id' id='category_id' value='0' />
      <input type='hidden' name='view' id='cf-query-view' value='H' />
      <div class='search-form-input-wrapper'>
        <div class='input-placeholder-group form-group mobile-browser mobidates start_date '>
          <label class='text-contrast'>Check-in</label>
          <input autocomplete='off' required type='text' id='cf-query-start_date' class=' date form-control' value='' data-alt='#alt_cf-query-start_date' data-datepicker='' />
          <input type='hidden' name='start_date' id='alt_cf-query-start_date' class='alt_date' value='2016-11-04'>
        </div>
        <div class='input-placeholder-group form-group mobile-browser mobidates end_date '>
          <label class='text-contrast'>Check-out</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This places 'Date range' before 'Check-in' (doesn't replace).  Also it doesn't hide 'Check-out'.  Thank you for your response though!

Comment: @winterfrost Of course it work, take a look at your last div in the missing html you posted

Comment: @winterfrost Updated my answer with the code you added to your question

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand.  I'm completely new to this on a steep learning curve :-/

Comment: @winterfrost You have 2 div's, one with a class named `start_date` and one with `end_date`, so by using those classes one can't take out the Check in/out labels and then add the Date Range using the pseudo `::before`

Comment: No, sorry, there has been no change with your suggested update.  :(

Comment: @winterfrost Well as the above code obviously works, you must have missed something when added my two CSS rules to your code, ... or the code you posted is not 100% copy of the one you actually use

Comment: It is a true copy.  Do I have to replace the div and labels?  I tried that too...

Answer (score 1):

Hiding the check-out text is easy:

```
.end_date .text-contrast {
  display: none;
}
```

We're missing the `div` that holds the first `.text-contrast` element, but can make an assumption that it has the class `.start_date` (or similar) based on how the second `div` has `.end_date`.  Therefore this should work for changing the text that's displayed:

```
.start_date .text-contrast {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
.start_date .text-contrast::before {
  content: 'Date range';
  position: absolute;
  text-indent: 0;
}
```

Comment: I used this to hide 'Check-out', but the rest of your suggestions haven't worked.  
 'code' .end_date .text-contrast {
  position: relative;
text-indent: -9999px;
}

Comment: Whoops. `.start_date .text-contrast` also needs to be `display: block;` or `display: inline-block` (depending on how the page lays out) for the `text-indent` property to work.

Comment: Not sure I understand you. This places 'Date range' *on top of* 'Check-in'. I have tried this: `.start_date .text-contrast display: block{
  position: relative;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
.start_date .text-contrast::before {
  content: 'Date range';
  position: absolute;
  text-indent: 0;
}`

Comment: Used this to *hide* 'Check-in' and 'Check-out' but still haven't been able to replace 'Check-in' without that *also* being indented/hidden (the second part of your answer didn't help): `.end_date .text-contrast {
  position: relative;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
.start_date .text-contrast {
  position: relative;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}`

Comment: Edited my original answer to show you where `display: block;` was meant to go. If the text box is meant to be flush against the label, change `block` to `inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are able to only edit stuff from CSS level, and you are not able to edit HTML files then the only reasonable way is :

```
.text-contrast {
  display: none;
}
.text-contrast:after {
  content: 'Date range';
}
```

but remember that it will apply to all `text-contrast` elements, so if you have more of those in the code, then probably you seriously need to change the HTML somehow.

Comment: Both Check-in and Check-out share the same CSS selector so your psuedo element would not appear. You'll need more specific selectors to prevent this.

Answer (score -2):

i think it's better to show and hide instead of delete as you see ,i added class Shw,hdn

```
<label class='text-contrast Shw'>Check-in</label>
<label class='text-contrast Hdn'>Date Range</label>
            <input autocomplete='off' required type='text' id='cf-query-start_date' class=' date form-control' value='' data-alt='#alt_cf-query-start_date' data-datepicker=''/>
                <input type='hidden' name='start_date' id='alt_cf-query-start_date' class='alt_date' value='2016-11-04'>
        </div>
        <div class='input-placeholder-group form-group mobile-browser mobidates end_date '>
            <label class='text-contrast'>Check-out</label>
```

Comment: If the OP could add classes to the markup, why wouldn't they simply update the markup instead?

Comment: we can change change the HTMl using javascript or jquery , but i don't think useing Css to edit in the html content

Comment: JS wasn't tagged as in the post so it might not be a viable option for the OP.